# Docker error on an entrypoint script: "no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm using Docker image `ubuntu:trusty` and have an `entrypoint.sh` file contains

```
#!/bin/bash
. /appenv/bin/activate
exec $@
```

In `Dockerfile` contains for entrypoint scripts

```
ADD scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

got an error `exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Comment: Are you running your Docker instance on a Windows?

Comment: Not in windows. In ububtu

Comment: the entrypoint shoudl be `ENTRYPOINT["./entrypoint.sh"]` or `ENTRYPOINT ["sh","entrypoint.sh"]`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am quite convinced that this is a common scenario where this error is caused by using wrong lines endings in entrypoint scripts.

You can use `dos2unix` command to fix them or do this manually.

For a more detailed answer, you need to provide more contextual info.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using VSCode,open the entrypoint-dev.sh file, and do this:

1. Click on the CRLF,
2. Change it to LF from the dropdown
3. Rebuild all the images & containers

[image]

Comment: What did we just do here? It worked for me like god!

Comment: How is this working? I don't remember changing this setting and yet it was set to CRLF. It's fixed, thank you.

Comment: God bless you, lost more than 1 hour trying to solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, of course it was a line-ending issue.  It was obvious once you know the solution, :).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

Run `dos2unix` command on your `entrypoint.sh` file. Above error is caused by incorrect line endings. This command will converts plain text files in DOS/MAC format to UNIX format.

**Example usage:**

```
dos2unix entrypoint.sh
```

Fix any errors that come up and run the build again. Follow [this link](https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025/4) for more information

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem with Docker for Windows and the solution was changing the entrypoint script file from CRLF -> LF.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, my entrypoint script had a typo in its [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), resulting in the same error

```
-#!bin/sh
+#!/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the entrypoint was indeed copied during the build phase, but my docker-compose was sharing a volume at the same path, so it was getting overrided.

Make sure your entrypoint is not in a directory where you mount a volume.